# kotlin test of async seems to blocks in main routine, but main never starts processing again

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, coroutine, channel

Note: I have edited the test after finding Kotlin doc on tests for coroutines.  I've switched from runBlocking to runTest(UnconfinedTestDispatcher()), with no difference.
I've included the trace at the end...

I'm writing a test in android studio with JUNIT5 test harness.  I'm creating two coroutines that I want to start by sending a start message over a channel.  One routine sends the other 6 messages, then sends a message to indicate end of messages.  The other receives the messages, notes the last and recognizes the end message and ends.

The sender returns the number of messages it sent.  The receiver return the last message which is really just the count.

The main routine that started the two coroutines, does a await() to get the
returns from the coroutines.

The test times out.  It never gets to the await() statements.  It seems that the processing of main stops when the second coroutine starts, but never starts again after both coroutines have returned their results.

Here is the code I threw together that illustrates this problem:

=====
@Test
@Timeout(6) // Three second limit to test - Just safety
fun `Two Coroutines basic channel test`() = runTest(UnconfinedTestDispatcher()) {

```
    val messagesToSend:Int = 6

    val coroutineChannel = Channel<Int>()
    val startChannel = Channel<Boolean>()

    val receiver = async() {
        println("receiver : in thread : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        var lastMessage:Int = 0
        for (start in startChannel) {
            if (start) {
                // we got a start message
                for (crmessage in coroutineChannel) {
                    if (crmessage < 0) { break }
                    lastMessage = crmessage
                    println("receiver: $crmessage")
                }
            }
            break
        }
        println("receiver: Finished")
        lastMessage // return for async
    }

    /**
     * sender will send messagesToSend messages at 333 ms per message.  For 6, 3 seconds
     */
    val sender = async() {
        println("sender : in thread : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        with (startChannel) {
            for (count in 1..messagesToSend ) {
                coroutineChannel.send(count)
                println("sender: $count")
                delay(333)
            }
        }
        // then send a -1 to close the receiver
        coroutineChannel.send(-1)

        println("sender: Finished")
        messagesToSend
    }

    println("main: before start")
    startChannel.send(true)
    println("main: start sent")
    startChannel.send(true)
    println("main: start sent")

    val messagesReceived:Int = receiver.await()
    val messagesSent:Int = sender.await()

    assertEquals(messagesToSend, messagesSent)
    assertEquals(messagesToSend, messagesReceived)

}
```

=====

Here is the output from the test:

receiver : in thread : Test worker @coroutine#2
sender : in thread : Test worker @coroutine#3
main: before start
receiver: 1
sender: 1
main: start sent
sender: 2
receiver: 2
sender: 3
receiver: 3
sender: 4
receiver: 4
sender: 5
receiver: 5
sender: 6
receiver: 6
sender: Finished
receiver: Finished

Two Coroutines basic channel test() timed out after 6 seconds

============================================================

Note that the 2d "mail: start send" is never printed, though clearly it the second message was sent since both coroutines are running.

In the debugger, the return value statement for each coroutine is reached and has the correct value.

Seems that both coroutines and the main routine are in the same thread, but it seems
that control should return to main.  Blocking should be released if I'm understanding coroutines correctly.

=== stack trace ===

Two Coroutines basic channel test() timed out after 6 seconds
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Two Coroutines basic channel test() timed out after 6 seconds
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutInvocation.createTimeoutException(TimeoutInvocation.java:70)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutInvocation.proceed(TimeoutInvocation.java:59)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Suppressed: java.lang.InterruptedException
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:84)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt.createTestResult(TestBuildersJvm.kt:13)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(TestBuilders.kt:308)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(Unknown Source)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(TestBuilders.kt:166)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(Unknown Source)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0$default(TestBuilders.kt:158)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0$default(Unknown Source)
at com.mortarandpestlesoftware.utilities.DirectorChannelsSupplementalTests.Two Coroutines basic channel test(DirectorChannelsSupplementalTests.kt:118)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutInvocation.proceed(TimeoutInvocation.java:46)
... 83 more
Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet
at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.getCompletionExceptionOrNull(JobSupport.kt:1194)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:368)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.ScopeCoroutine.afterResume(Scopes.kt:32)
at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.resumeWith(AbstractCoroutine.kt:102)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:280)
at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.shutdown(EventLoop.common.kt:225)
at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.decrementUseCount(EventLoop.common.kt:113)
at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.decrementUseCount$default(EventLoop.common.kt:107)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:91)
... 103 more

Comment: In light of morning, I've found doc on tests for kotlin coroutines : [HERE](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test) and migration instructions circa 2022 at [MIGRATION](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/MIGRATION.md)... trying it now...

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, I tried using the test harness for coroutines.  I replaced runBlocking with runTest.   Also am usng  UnconfinedTestDispatcher().  NO difference in results.  I'm changing the code to reflect runTest() usage.